# GKE Error: no matches for kind "BackendConfig" in version "cloud.google.com/v1"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-armor

I am trying to follow [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cloud-armor-backendconfig) on configuring Cloud Armor and I'm getting this error when trying to apply it to create a BackendConfig. Why am I getting this error? Clearly they're saying there should be an api config type of BackendConfig.

`no matches for kind “BackendConfig” in version “cloud.google.com/v1”`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommand to tring api version “cloud.google.com/v1beta1” instead “cloud.google.com/v1”. [The issue with V1 BackendConfig is that it is supported only in GKE 1.16.8-gke.3](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/backendconfig), So, if you are not using GKE 1.16.8-gke.3 it might not work. Could you share what version of the  GKE you are using?

Comment: Why does the documentation I was using not say this?

Comment: We're using 1.14.10-gke.27. I was able to apply a backendconfig using the beta url but when adding the annotation for it in a given deployment resource config it didn't do anything. No new targets in the cloud armor policy.